# How to execute Datatable Linq Union

Tags: linq, datatable, left-join

I have a datatable that contains below data.

```
Table 1
    880000000010747
    880000000012235
    880000000000010
    880000000015086
    880000000000028        
Table 2
    880000000014718
    880000000014928
    880000000009684
    880000000013184
    880000000010747
```

How can i union the tables and return the result below?

```
    880000000010747
    880000000012235
    880000000000010
    880000000015086
    880000000000028
    880000000014718
    880000000014928
    880000000009684
    880000000013184
```

Answer (score 0):

From .Net 3.5 to 4.5 (at time on writing) you can use the Union method

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386993%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

C# Example:

```
var infoQuery =
    (from cust in db.Customers
    select cust.Country)
    .Union
        (from emp in db.Employees
        select emp.Country)
;
```

VB.net Example:

```
Dim infoQuery = _
    (From cust In db.Customers _
    Select cust.Country) _
    .Union _
        (From emp In db.Employees _
        Select emp.Country)
```

If you to join all regardless of duplicates check out the Concat Method:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Miscellaneous-6b72bb2a#Concat1

Hope that helps.